# Getting error add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'override_quantity' in Django

Tags: python, django

When I run the URL http://localhost:8000/cart/add/1/ it gives me error:  **TypeError: add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'override_quantity'**. Can anyone please help me why I'm getting this error? here I have added my whole code.

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'cart'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
path('add/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_add, name='cart_add'),
path('remove/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1,21)]

class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices = PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES, coerce=int)

    override = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial = False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

views.py

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], override_quantity=cd['override'])           
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')            

@require_POST
def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

Comment: Can you share your models? and the `Cart` logic?

Comment: `Cart` is a class written by yourself? How is it implemented? It seems, that the `add` method does not accept the argument `override_quantity`.

Comment: I can't share my models.py file because stack overflow gives me the error!!!. it gives me the your question is fully code.!!

Comment: this is my card.py link https://codeshare.io/8pv7A4

Comment: You made a typo in the `add` method: it is `override_quantity` with *two* `r`s, not `overide_quantity`.